# numpy warning with django 4 - 'numpy.float64'> type is zero

Tags: python, django, numpy

I just updated numpy and I get the following warning with Django. How can I fix it?

> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py:89:
> UserWarning: The value of the smallest subnormal for <class
> 'numpy.float64'> type is zero.

Comment: downgraded numpy to numpy==1.21.4 and the warning was gone

Answer (score 4):

In my case this was some kind of compatability issue between a custom compiled version of opencv and numpy 1.22. The workaround to stop the warnings was the do the following.

```
import numpy as np

np.finfo(np.dtype("float32"))
np.finfo(np.dtype("float64"))
import cv2
```

You may find a variation of this will suppress the warnings for you.

I've filed a bug report with numpy but I'm not sure if it's something that's easy to figure out or not.
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20895

Answer (score 3):

I get the same warning in a virtual environment when using `numpy 1.22.1` installed via `pip` and `opencv 4.5.3` compiled from source. Interestingly, using the exact same package versions (installed from conda/conda-forge) in an anaconda environment does not yield the warning.

From the discussion in @Peter's [bug report](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20895), opencv modifies numpy so that it replaces very small values with zeros. Thus the warning is useful, and may be intended behavior:

> OpenCV has the habit of setting the floating point handling to "flush
> to zero". There is a good reason for wanting to do that: flushing to
> zero is much faster and all you lose are extremely small values (I had
> some diffusion simulations once where things would be extremely slow
> if activity stopped, because the system kept calculating these almost
> 0 values).
>
> I honestly thought that they had done something about that, we had not
> had issues opened for a long time ;)... It seems that this is even the
> case for subnormal == 0 though, flushing the subnormal to zero before
> the comparison (even though it is returned correctly).
>
> Frankly, giving you a warning here in a sense serves exactly its
> purpose. That value may not be zero, but it is treated as zero due to
> cv2 import messing with NumPy. So using the smallest subnormal will be
> meaningless in many contexts because of that import cv2.

@Peter's solution did not eliminate the numpy warning for me, but downgrading to numpy 1.21 did.

```py
pip install numpy==1.21
```